# Spring boot microservice not pushing logs to logstash

Tags: java, spring-boot, logstash, microservices, elastic-stack

I have a microservice which is not pushing logs to logstash

For Centralized logging i am using ELK Stack, which is running in Docker Container

I am using logback.xml in my spring boot code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread, %X{X-B3-TraceId:-},%X{X-B3-SpanId:-}] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="STASH"
        class="net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender">
        <destination>192.168.99.100:5045</destination>



        <encoder
            class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder">
            <providers>
                <mdc /> <!-- MDC variables on the Thread will be written as JSON fields -->
                <context /> <!--Outputs entries from logback's context -->
                <version /> <!-- Logstash json format version, the @version field in the output -->
                <logLevel />
                <loggerName />

                <pattern>
                    <pattern>
                        {
                        "serviceName": "order-service"
                        }
                    </pattern>
                </pattern>

                <threadName />
                <message />
                <logstashMarkers />
                <stackTrace />
            </providers>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="STASH" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

This is my logstash.conf file

```
input {
    tcp {
        port => 5045
        codec => json
   }
}

output {
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => [ "http://192.168.99.100:9200" ]
        index => "micro-%{serviceName}"
    }
}
```

So when i am trying to create index in Kibana, i am not getting any result.

Any help on this is appreciated

Comment: Are the containers running in the same network so that they can see each other? you can check that with "docker inspect container_name" for each of them and make sure the network is the same. You should also replace the IP with the container name (verify it with "docker ps").

Comment: yes its in the same network

Comment: Can you see your stdout logs with the ruby debug codec ?